# Magento2: Cant change store in product listing and product detail page

Tags: multistore, magento2.2, language

I have successfully created multistore with different languages with URLs like:

```
http://localhost/magento22/english/
http://localhost/magento22/french/
```

I can change store only in homepage. When I go in product detail page or product listing page, I am unable to switch store. When I click on french store it always redirects to existing(English) store.

**This is Magento 2.2 default issue**

Comment: I have same issue please anyone help me and @Jaimin

Answer (score 0):

can you refer this

- Language Switcher is not working on Magento 2.2.3 #14674 https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/14674

  and also refer this
- Language switcher redirects to the homepage on Magento 2.2.5 #16758 https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/16758
  it's Magento 2.2.X issue